# How to check who edited the channel on Discord through channelUpdate event

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm creating the `updateChannel` event, however, as I go through the Discord.JS Docs I couldn't seem to find or figure out who edited the channel; or is that even possible? I will provide the current code that I have below this message.

Discord.JS: `v12.2.0`

```
client.on("channelUpdate", async(oldChannel, newChannel) => {
  if(oldChannel.type === "dm") return undefined;

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Channel Updated", oldChannel.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))

    oldChannel.send(embed)
});
```

Comment: I think you will need to use the guild audit log for that

Comment: @Giuliopime Someone told me that as well, to fetch information from the audit log. However, I am not entirely sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you need to [fetch audit logs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs):

```js
oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 11, limit: 1 }) // CHANNEL_UPDATE
  .then((logs) => {
     embed.setDescription(logs.entries.first().executor); // Get First from Collection of GuildAuditLogs, and its executor.
     oldChannel.send(embed);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'executor' of undefined`